# Höfliche Anrede mit zweiter Person Plural: »Ihr solltet zugeben, dass Ihr ganz einfach Angst habt.«

Tags: usage, politeness

Die zweite Person Plural wird ab und zu verwendet, um Höflichkeit auszudrücken. Folgendes Beispiel stammt aus dem Buch "Die unendliche Geschichte" von Michael Ende:

> »Held Hynreck«, sagte Bastian langsam, »anstatt mich der Lüge zu bezichtigen, solltet Ihr lieber zugeben, daß Ihr ganz einfach Angst habt.«

Wann wird diese Höflichkeitsform benutzt? Ist es höflicher als das übliche Siezen?

In Geschäften höre ich ab und zu »Habt ihr die Hose auch in einer anderen Größe?«, aber ich vermute, dass diese Anrede nicht besonders höflich gemeint ist, sondern dass es sich um einen normalen Plural in der zweiten Person handelt.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/77/23

Comment: [Als Höflichkeitsform der 3. Person Singular (sehr selten, veraltet) wird Ihr immer großgeschrieben.](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ihr)

Comment: Welche 3. Person? `Schau Inge! Sie hat ihr Taschentuch verloren.` ist 3. Person. `Frau Vogelblick! Sie haben Ihr Taschentuch verloren!` ist 2. Person i.d. Höflickkeitsform. 'Sire, habt Ihr wohl dinieret?` ist auch 2. Person, aber veraltet, und `Ihr` ist hier kein besitzanzeigendes Fürwort, wie beim Taschentuch. Die Frage war aber: "Wann wird diese Höflichkeitsform benutzt?", und ich habe die Frage so verstanden, dass wir erklären sollen, wann der Frager es benutzen soll, und meine Antwort ist `gar nicht`, weil es veraltet ist. Ob man's groß schreibt - bestreitet das jmd.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Geschäften handelt es sich tatsächlich nur um den Plural. Man könnte dort auch "Haben Sie die Hose in einer anderen Größe?" sagen.

Die höfliche Anrede mit der zweiten Person ist veraltet und klingt so, als würde man mit einem König oder einem Kaiser sprechen. Man findet sie häufig in Fantasy-Romanen oder Geschichten die z.B. im Mittelalter spielen, wenn Angehörige niederer Stände mit Angehörigen hörerer Stände sprechen. Ein Beispiel könnte ein Bauer sein, der mit seinem [Lehnsherren](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehnsherr) redet. Oder wenn jemand wie hier z.B. einen berühmten edlen Helden anspricht.

(siehe auch [de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Höflichkeitsform#Pronomen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6flichkeitsform#Pronomen) für einige wenige Beispiele.)

Comment: Zu "Habt ihr diese Hose...": M.E. ist das nur dann zulässig, wenn man auch den Verkäufer selber duzen würde (oder dies tut). Denn es ist ja der Plural von "Hast Du diese Hose...". Daher würde ich den Plural "ihr" als unhöflich empfinden, wenn im Singular das "Sie" angebracht wäre. Kurz: m.E. grundsätzlich unhöflich, nur in Ausnahmefällen ok.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Richtig, es wäre unhöflich, wenn *Sie* korrekt wäre. Aber wenn du mal in einem Laden mit einer jüngeren Zielgruppe Klamotten gekauft hast, wirst du festgestellt haben, dass dort geduzt wird, wie das ja mitunter üblich ist. Wobei ich da auch eher sieze :) In historischen Romanen oder Filmen wird der Plural auch gerne verwendet, selbst wenn es sich nicht um Standesunterschiede handelt - ob das historisch korrekt ist, sei aber dahingestellt.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Zustimmung, Euer Ehren ;-)

Comment: Interessant wäre, ob wir wirklich unseren König mit "Ihr" anreden würden, wenn wir eine Monarchie wie andere europäische Länder hätten.

Comment: Das klingt jetzt zwar etwas seltsam, aber meine Frau und ich sprechen meine Schwiegermutter tatsächlich (im Dialekt) mit "Ihr" (eigentlich dialektal *"Ess"*) an; hat nichts mit Adel oder ähnlichem zu tun; es war früher üblich, die Bäuerin so zu nennen - auch als Tochter oder Sohn. Es ist unglaublich, wie schnell man so was nicht mehr als seltsam empfindet. In der Verwendung wird eine gewisse Form von Respekt ausgedrückt, auch wenn viele es als Hierarchie-Bekundung wahrnehmen, was m. E. nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: @splattne
Sehr interessant. Ich kannte "Ess" bisher nur in Pluralwendungen.

Comment: @thei Ja, ist auch Plural wie *Ihr*. In unserem (südtiroler) Dialekt lauten die persönlichen Pronomen: *i (=ich), du, er/sie/es, mir (=wir), ess (=ihr), sie*

Comment: In Yiddish the singular forms are the same as German, but for plural forms we have mir, ihr (also polite singular) and see.