# Was versteht man im Deutschen unter einer "Familie"?

Tags: semantics

Der Duden erklärt "Familie" als "aus einem Elternpaar oder einem Elternteil und mindestens einem Kind bestehende [Lebens]gemeinschaft".

Sind ein Mann und eine Frau ohne Kinder nicht auch eine Familie?

Answer (score 13):

**Sprachgebrauch**

Nach einer [Umfrage, bei der Doppelnennungen möglich waren](http://www.bertelsmann-stiftung.de/bst/de/media/xcms_bst_dms_18377__2.pdf), verstehen rund 90% der 18- bis 44jährigen unter einer "Familie" ein verheiratetes Ehepaar mit Kindern; nur rund 23% verstehen auch ein verheiratetes Paar ohne Kinder als "Familie".

> - 91% - Ein verheiratetes Ehepaar mit Kindern
> - 62% - Ein unverheiratet zusammenlebendes Paar mit Kindern
> - 62% - Drei Generationen, die zusammenleben: Großeltern, Eltern, Kinder
> - 41% - Ein allein erziehender Vater, eine allein erziehende Mutter mit Kind
> - 23% - Ein verheiratetes Paar ohne Kinder
> - 16% - Ein unverheiratet zusammenlebendes Paar ohne Kinder
> - 13% - Zwei Männer oder zwei Frauen, die in einer festen Lebensgemeinschaft leben
> - 2% - Nichts davon

Neben diesem alltäglichen Sprachverständnis, bei dem die Bedeutung "Eltern(teil) mit Kind(ern)" klar überwiegt, gibt es unterschiedliche Familiendefinitionen in unterschiedlichen Wissenschaften.

**Recht**

Das deutsche Recht verzichtet auf eine Definition des Begriffes Familie und verwendet, vom Grundgesetz abgesehen (Schutz der Familie) die Begriffe "Verwandtschaft" und "Gemeinschaft". Konservative Rechtswissenschaftler bestimmen als Familie im Sinne des Grundgesetzes die Gemeinschaft von Eltern und Kindern.

**Politik**

Der politische Sprachgebrauch der Gegenwart versteht unter "Familie" einen "Ort, an dem Kinder leben".

**Soziologie**

Die Soziologie spricht von "Familie" oder "familiären Lebensformen", wenn Erwachsene mit verwandten oder adoptierten Kindern zusammenleben. Andere Formen des Zusammenlebens haben andere Bezeichnungen, z.B. die "Ehe", die "Nichteheliche Lebensgemeinschaft ohne Kinder" oder die "Wohngemeinschaft".

**Psychologie**

Aus Sicht der Psychologie ist für eine Familie (unter anderem) entscheidend die intime Lebensgemeinschaft und die Sorge um die nächste Generation. Dabei entstehen der gemeinsame Raum und die Intimität auch über eine räumliche Trennung hinweg, z.B. wenn erwachsene Kinder aus dem Elternhaus ausgezogen sind und der Kontakt überwiegend über das Telefon stattfindet. In diesem Sinne *gehören* ein Paar ohne Kinder zu einer (oder zwei) Familien, *sind* aber für sich keine Familie.

**Statistik**

"Die Familie im statistischen Sinn umfasst im Mikrozensus [des Statistischen Bundesamtes] alle Eltern-Kind-Gemeinschaften ... Damit besteht eine statistische Familie immer aus zwei Generationen (Zwei-Generationen-Regel): Eltern/-teile und im Haushalt lebende ledige Kinder."

Quellen:

- Duden, s.v. Familie
- http://www.bertelsmann-stiftung.de/bst/de/media/xcms_bst_dms_18377__2.pdf
- http://www.gbe-bund.de/gbe10/abrechnung.prc_abr_test_logon?p_uid=gastg&p_aid=&p_knoten=FID&p_sprache=D&p_suchstring=2089::Ehepaare,%20Ehepaar
- http://www.br-online.de/jugend/izi/text/petzold.pdf

Comment: Interessant sind bei der Umfrage auch die unteren 2% ;)

Comment: @Takkat Das kann viele Gründe haben. Familie hat ja noch andere Bedeutungen. So könnten einige der Befragten der Meinung sein, ihre Familie seien alle ihre Verwandten (Sippe). Vielleicht ist das eine Bedeutung, die bei unseren Mitbürgern mit Migrationshintergrund vorherrscht. Russen z.B. verstehen auch Onkel und Tanten, die nicht im Haus leben, als zur Familie gehörig. Auch Türken haben eher Großfamilien, die über's ganze Dorf verteilt sind. Insofern widersprechen die 2% Sonstige weder der Bedeutung "Erwachsene und Kinder", noch machen sie die übrigen Antworten ungültig.

Comment: Wenn ich so darüber nachdenke, merke ich, dass auch in meinem Sprachgebrauch "Familie" die Bedeutung haben kann, die deutlich über die wie auch immer zusammengesetzte häusliche Wohngemeinschaft hinausgeht. Die "Familie", die bei einem "Familienfest" zusammenkommt, beinhaltet beispielsweise definitiv auch Onkels, Tanten, Cousinen, Cousins usw. "Familie" ist dann Synonym zu "Verwandtschaft" verwendet. Welche "Familie" genau gemeint ist, mag vom Kontext und auch dem Adressaten der Aussage abhängen, und kann zudem über Attribute wie "ganze Familie" oder "erweiterte Familie" verdeutlicht werden.