# Wird es höflich, fremde, ältere Erwachsene zu duzen, auch in professionellem Umfeld?

Tags: politeness, address, evolution

In der deutschen Sprache gibt es neben der familiären Anrede »du« die höfliche Form »Sie«.
[Diese Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/85/16560) von 2011 erläutert den Gebrauch nach meinem Sprachgefühl sehr treffend.

Ich (Mitte 30) bin in Deutschland mit einem bestimmten Verständnis aufgewachsen, wann welche Form die richtige ist:
Leute, die so aussehen, als wären sie Teil der *Du-Kultur*, duze ich, die anderen sieze ich.
Ob jemand für mich auf den ersten Blick zu dieser Kultur gehört, hängt von verschiedenen Faktoren ab.
Es ist eine Frage des Alters, der Ausstrahlung, dem Kleidungsstil etc.: eben des Gesamteindrucks, den ich von der Person habe.
Meist liege ich damit richtig, das heißt, die Leute reagieren nicht irritiert, wenn ich »du« oder »Sie« verwende.

Heute habe ich erlebt, wie ein junger Fahrkartenkontrolleur (etwa 30 Jahre alt) in der U-Bahn ein älteres Pärchen (etwa 60 Jahre alt) mit zu günstig gelösten Fahrkarten (zu kleiner Geltungsbereich) »erwischte«.
Sie kamen vom Flughafen und der Mann sprach gutes Deutsch mit französischem Akzent.
Ich hätte die beiden auf jeden Fall gesiezt.

Der Kontrolleur entschied sich fürs *Du*.
Er sprach mit dem Mann und verwarnte ihn, ließ die beiden aber ansonsten ohne Strafe:

> Deine Karte gilt nur im Nahbereich.
>   Wenn du bis Hauptbahnhof fahren willst, musst du eine Fahrkarte für drei dreißig kaufen.
>   Diesmal mache ich eine Ausnahme, aber fürs nächste Mal weißt du Bescheid.

Ich empfand das als unhöflich oder zumindest ungewöhnlich.
Ist das ein Einzelfall oder geht der Gebrauch der Höflichkeitsform stark zurück?
Ist die oben verlinkte Antwort noch aktuell?

---

edit: Meine Frage ist kein Duplikat von »[How can a native English speaker know when it is appropriate to use the polite (Sie) or the familiar (Du)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/77/how-can-a-native-english-speaker-know-when-it-is-appropriate-to-use-the-polite)«:

1. Es geht nicht um Englischsprecher.
2. Hier geht es um eine mögliche Entwicklung im Sprachgebrauch.
3. Die verlinkte Antwort zu der englischen Frage ist von 2011.
   In meiner Frage wird die Aktualität der Antwort explizit in Frage gestellt.

Comment: Das war doch höchstwahrscheinlich in Berlin, oder? Die Berliner haben keine Sitten... (Ja, Pauschalurteile sind ungerecht)

Comment: Nein. Antwort hier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxI7NjMrn2I

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann: Also ich bin selbst Berliner (gebürtig und immer noch dort lebend) und auch ich wäre vom Verhalten dieses Kontrolettis eher befremdet. In meinem Kopf laufen bereits Spekulationen ab, aus welchem Milieu der wohl kommen mag...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Dein Kommentar ist zwar ironisch, aber trotzdem: Es war in Hamburg.

Comment: Die Frage ist eher, ob es **üblich** wird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um die Eingangsfrage als erstes zu beantworten: Nein, im deutschen wird es wohl auch in Zukunft nicht als höflich gelten ältere oder fremde Menschen einfach so zu duzen.

Jetzt das große "Aber"

Im Allgemeinem kann man eine stärkere Tendenz zum Duzen erkennen. Gerade auch im professionellen Businessumfeld. Unternehmen die sich ein junges oder hippes Image verpassen wollen setzen gerne auf eine Unternehmensphilosophie, in der sich alle Mitarbeiter gegenseitig duzen. Wie auch @volker in seiner Antwort schrieb kann man ähnliches etwa bei Fitnessstudio-Ketten erkennen, die ihre Mitglieder stets mit "Du" ansprechen, wobei dies sicher ein Ort ist an dem auch ansonsten schon immer gerne geduzt wurde. Andere Ketten die ebenfalls als jung gelten verfahren ähnlich bei der Ansprache ihrer Kunden. Gerade welche aus dem amerikanischen Raum.

In Amerika ist sowieso die Ansprache per Vornamen generell viel verbreiteter als hier, auch wenn diese nicht den zusätzlichen Spagat zwischen Du und Sie vollführen müssen, wie im Deutschen. Man denke nur an Konstrukte wie das "[Hamburger Sie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_Sie)", bzw. "Kassiererinnen-Du". Durch die Verpflechtung mit vielen deutschen Unternehmen, bzw. gemeinsame Geschäfte entstand ein gewisser Kulturaustausch der Business-Etikette, so dass man Geschäftspartner aus Amerika (und auch anderen Ländern) gerne duzt oder wenigstens mit dem Vornamen anspricht (vgl. [hier](https://www.business-spotlight.de/sprachratgeber/englische-anrede-vorname-oder-nachname)). Von dort aus ist es im deutschen dann auch ein nicht mehr so großer Schritt zum duzen. Man könnte also durchaus sagen, dass es auch im professionellen Businessumfeld eine größere Tendenz zum Du gibt, wobei es natürlich auch hier auf die Art des Unternehmens ankommt.

Wie aber schon in der Frage gesagt ist es im privaten öffentlichen Umfeld

> eine Frage des Alters, der Ausstrahlung, dem Kleidungsstil
>   etc.: eben des Gesamteindrucks, den ich von der Person habe

wie man jemanden anspricht. Allerdings auch eine Sache der persönlichen Lebenssituation, inneren Einstellung und der Einschätzung der Beziehung/Rangunterschiede. Wer sonst auch viel duzt wird auch im öffentlichen Raum fremde Personen duzen, bzw. weniger Hemmungen haben dies zu machen. Das ist allerdings kein neues Phänomen, sondern kann man auch schon bei den Hippies in den 60ern erkennen die alles duzten und das in einer Zeit als dies noch komplett verpönt war.

Das Verhalten des Schaffners ist allerdings auch für mich unangebracht.

Comment: "sondern kann man schon bei den Hippies in den 60ern erkennen die alles duzten". Das war nicht nur die Hippies so. "Haste mal ne Mark" oder "Haste mal nen Euro" hat jeder schon gehört.

Answer (score 5):

Es ist ganz sicher so, dass immer mehr geduzt wird, aber in dem von Dir geschilderten Fall erscheint es mir definitiv unangebracht. Gerade weil der Kontrolleur in einer Position ist, die ihm Autorität verleiht, sollte er siezen.

Answer (score 2):

Da sich bisher niemand zu einer Antwort hat durchringen können...

Es könnte sein, dass die Anzahl der "abgeschlossenen Bereiche" (Firma, Fitnessstudio), in denen das Duzen standard ist, zugenommen hat. In der generellen Öffentlichkeit ist mir eine derartige Entwicklung aber nicht aufgefallen. Obwohl ich als ehemaliger Student und Judoka eine eher geringe Hemmschwelle gegen das Duzen habe, würde ich niemals auf die Idee kommen, einen mir völlig fremden Menschen außerhalb einer Gruppe, in der das üblich ist, mit Du anzureden.

Answer (score 1):

Da ich ein zunehmendes Duzen gegenüber fremden 60-Jährigen nicht feststelle, würde ich den Fall psychologisch erklären.

Der Kontrolleur mochte sich so etwas wie das hier gesagt haben:

> Da ich in diesem Fall die Macht habe, ein Bußgeld zu verhängen, muss ich nicht
>   sonderlich höflich sein. Das ein oder andere kann ich mir getrost herausnehmen; und wenn aufgemuckt wird, wird bezahlt.

Man kann das Ganze also als ein Beispiel für die Macht des kleinen Mannes ansehen.

Answer (score 1):

Angebracht war das Duzen in diesem Fall ganz sicher nicht. Ich würde es aber - noch - als Ausnahme werten.

Allerdings unterliegt das "Sie" einem starken Erosionsprozess.

Unter jungen Leuten (das möchte ich jetzt nicht mit einer Alterszahl präzisieren) ist es seit langem fast völlig verschwunden. Ich erinnere mich an ein Gespräch (ca. 1980) mit einer Russin, die von einem regelrechten Kulturschock berichtete, als sie in Deutschland zu studieren begann: Sie wurde von allen KommilitonInnen geduzt, in Russland war das (damals) völlig unüblich.

Ein weiterer Verfall des Siezens kommt über die Werbung. Meist wird man penetrant geduzt, nicht nur in der Werbung eines "unmöglichen Möbelhauses" aus Schweden.

Einige interessante Artikel zu diesem Thema: [Hier](https://www.brandeins.de/magazine/brand-eins-wirtschaftsmagazin/2018/naehe-und-distanz/siezen-sie-noch-oder-duzt-du-schon), [hier](https://www.rnd.de/kultur/du-telekom-hor-auf-deine-kunden-zu-duzen-C5DK3E2BDBFYRGMKUYDPLBNME4.html) und [hier](https://www.heise-regioconcept.de/online-marketing/duzen-oder-siezen). Das Ganze ist natürlich von Marktforschern analysiert worden, es geht wie üblich nur ums liebe Geld: Wie erreicht man die größte Zielgruppe? Wer es hochwissenschaftlich mag, kann sich [das](https://nanopdf.com/download/die-anrede-in-der-deutschen-werbung_pdf) ansehen.