# How do I thank someone for their help?

Tags: word-choice

In the context of a someone helping you with something, how do you thank he/she?

I was thinking "Danke für ihre Hilfe","Danke für deine Hilfe",or "Danke für die Hilfe". Which best conveys the meaning?

Comment: These are all ok, though using *ihre* makes you talking to a stranger. It's okay for people you just met or likely never see again. E.g. when someone helped you climbing a train. Also okay for your neighbor if you aren't yet friends with her.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should you use "du" instead of "Sie"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47744/when-should-you-use-du-instead-of-sie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Danke für die Hilfe will always be ok, so you don't need to worry about "Sie" and "du".